# Is there an easier way to remove old files on servers through GitHub after deleting files and syncing locally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, ssh, synchronization

I currently work with a web dev team and we have 100+ GitHub Repo's, each for a different e-commerce website that has an instance on AWS. The developers use the GitHub app to upload their changes to the servers, and do this multiple times a day.

I'm trying to find the easiest way for us to remove old, deleted files from our servers after we delete and sync GitHub locally.

To make it clear, say we have an index.html, page1.html and page2.html. We want to remove page1.html, so they delete page1.html and sync through the GitHub app. The file is no longer visibly in the repo, but for us to completely remove the file I must also SSH into our AWS server, go to the www directory and find page1.html and also remove it there. Is there an easier way for the developers, who do not use SSH and the command line, to get rid of those files in terms of syncing with GitHub? It becomes a pain to have to SSH into many different servers and then determining which files were removed from the repo so that I can remove them there.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Something we do with our repo is we use tags(releases) and then through automation ([chef](/questions/tagged/chef) in our case) we tell it to pull the new tag. It sounds like this wouldn't necessarily work for you but what Chef actually does with the tag might be of interest

It pulls the tag and then updates a symlink (and graceful restarts Apache). This means there's 0 downtime (symlink updates instantly) and, because it's pulling a fresh copy, any deleted files are gone.

Comment: hmm interesting. I might have to look into that, although we decided to roll with Ansible rather than Chef (through the chain of command). I was hoping there was an easier way that I just didn't know about that didn't require more downloads or anything, but at the same time I am open to any ideas. Thanks!